# Function stops for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a loop that is deleting items from an array, but it has to use that array to remove something else (poll.results items) corresponding with the array items. For some reason, when this loop runs it only deletes one item, then stops. I don't really know what else I could do to fix this as I don't really get an error. Again, all of the functions work exactly as intended, but using a loop with these function seems to only make the loop run the first iteration...

```
poll = {
  results: {
    'test 1': 1,
    'test 2': 1,
    'test 3': 1
  },
  users: {
    'someid': ['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3']
  },
  title: 'some title',
  author: 'someid'
}

function purgeUser(id) {
    if (poll.users.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < poll.users[id].length; i++) {
            removeUserVote(id, i + 1);
            write('current', poll);
        }
    }
}

function removeUserVote(id, index) {
    if (poll.users.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        // assuming the index is 1 2 3 from discord chat
        if (index <= poll.users[id].length && index > 0) {
            downvote(poll.users[id][index - 1]);
            poll.users[id].splice(index - 1, 1);

            if (!poll.users[id].length)
                delete poll.users[id];
        }
    }
}

function downvote(name) {
    if (poll.results.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        if (poll.results[name] === 1)
            delete poll.results[name];
        else
            poll.results[name]--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Click the `<>` snippet editor, add your object in a [mcve]

Comment: Show us the object `poll.users`

Comment: Your `for ()` loop keeps checking that `i < poll.users[id].length` but you're changing the `.length` in the loop body by `delete`ing (and `splice()`ing) items from `poll.users[id]`

Comment: Yeah - use `for (let i = poll.users[id].length; i > 0; --i) {`